# foreach powershell loop open items

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a a lot of files that are windows themepacks that I want to open up. I don't want to just go down the list and double-click each one. So I sent the get-childitem to the variable $item and then loop through it, next I want to open each file. Just using the name and ./windows7.theme works however code doesn't. I have tried the different options below and they don't work, please help. Also, let me know of any other methods to open files through PowerShell

```
foreach($item in $i){$a=$item.name;./$a}
foreach($item in $i){$a=$item.name;./($a)}
foreach($item in $i){./($item.name)}
```

[image: image of error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
invoke-item $a
```

The Invoke-Item cmdlet performs the default action on the specified item. For example, it runs an executable file or opens a document
file in the application associated with the document file type.

more info:

```
get-help invoke-item -full
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try this

```
$baselocation  = (Get-Location).Path + "\Desktop\"
$fileExtension = ".txt"
foreach($itm in $var)
{
    &($baselocation+ $itm.name + $fileExtension)
}
```

My file which just lists the name of the other files are in C:\users\user1\Desktop

Source: [Invocation Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6)